# SQL Server 2016 Mirroring failed, but database is in Recovery state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-mirroring

I'm trying to setup mirroring in SQL Server 2016 using SSMS, but it's not working. It's failing, and after a lot of retries still I'm not able to set this up. Post restoring backups the database state was "Restoring", but after trying to setup mirroring, it's state changed to In-Recovery, but mirroring didn't succeed. Getting message like DB can't be opened, it is in the middle of restore.
[image]

Comment: You provided not enough information so far. Can you provide all exception messages you received during setup of mirroring.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to open the mirror instance anyways. It's not operational, unless you do a fallover where the mirror instance becomes the principal, and it becomes operational.